# Displaying Eigenfaces with negative values

Tags: image-processing, numpy, face-recognition

After implementing the Eigenfaces algorithm for python using numpy, I noticed that the normalized eigenvectors contained negative values. How are these negative values represented when the eigenface is displayed as an image, like [this](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Vision/Faces/Eigenface.jpg)? I thought that images consisted of positive intensity values. Are these eigenface images generated by histogram equalization on the eigenvector?

Comment: Since this is just an assumption / guess I won't put it forward as an answer, but I'd think the normalized range -1:1 is just mapped onto 0:255 directly.

Answer (score 1):

The plotting of negative values depends on the implementation of the plotting function. Matlab's `imagesc`, for example, scales image data to the full range of the current colormap and displays the image. This is simpler than histogram equalization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for visualization purposes, just map `min(eigenface)` to 0 and `max(eigenface)` to 255. Your linked image appears to be doing that. (Note how each eigenface occupies the full dynamic range.)

Eigenfaces (or eigenvectors, in general) will likely have positive and negative elements.